# React Native using picker to select country & flag

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I would like to know how to implement React Native picker to select a country and an image of the flag. Any help would be appreciated

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View, Image, Picker } from 'react-native'

export default class country extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { country: ""};
        this.state = {updatedCountry};
      }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Picker selectedValue = {this.state.country} onValueChange = {this.updatedCountry}>
               <Picker.Item label = "America" value = "flag" />
               <Picker.Item label = "England" value = "Flag" />
            </Picker>
            <Text style = {styles.text}>{this.state.country}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: What part exactly are you having problems with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just came across this react-native library [react-native-country-picker-modal](https://github.com/xcarpentier/react-native-country-picker-modal) while looking for the same.

Supports both Android and iOS

[image: example]

Uses [world-countries](https://www.npmjs.com/package/world-countries) to populate the list.

If you are very keen you can check out the internals of the implementation [src/CountryPicker.js](https://github.com/xcarpentier/react-native-country-picker-modal/blob/master/src/CountryPicker.js), [scripts/transform-world-countries.js](https://github.com/xcarpentier/react-native-country-picker-modal/blob/master/scripts/transform-world-countries.js), [src/countryFlags.js](https://github.com/xcarpentier/react-native-country-picker-modal/blob/master/src/countryFlags.js)

Comment: This is using ListView which is deprecated now and causing warnings

Comment: please see https://github.com/xcarpentier/react-native-country-picker-modal/issues/211 for ListView is deprecated

Comment: Not able to customize country list

Comment: how to resize the flag?